# Selenium driver.execute_script return None

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I need to check if the element I need is in the visibility zone, if yes - return True, otherwise - False:

```
driver.execute_script('window.pageYOffset+document.querySelector(arguments[0]).getBoundingClientRect().bottom>window.pageYOffset&&window.pageYOffset+document.querySelector(arguments[0]).getBoundingClientRect().top<window.pageYOffset+document.documentElement.clientHeight&&window.pageXOffset+document.querySelector(arguments[0]).getBoundingClientRect().right>window.pageXOffset&&(window.pageXOffset,document.querySelector(arguments[0]).getBoundingClientRect().left,window.pageXOffset,document.documentElement.clientWidth),return True;', 'a.pagination-next')
```

But this script always returns None

```
if (window.pageYOffset + document.querySelector(arguments[0]).getBoundingClientRect().bottom > window.pageYOffset && 
window.pageYOffset + document.querySelector(arguments[0]).getBoundingClientRect().top < window.pageYOffset + document.documentElement.clientHeight &&
window.pageXOffset + document.querySelector(arguments[0]).getBoundingClientRect().right > window.pageXOffset &&
window.pageXOffset + document.querySelector(arguments[0]).getBoundingClientRect().left < window.pageXOffset + document.documentElement.clientWidth) {return True;};
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is the only language that capitalizes True and False. Try it like this:

```
driver.execute_script('''
 return (
   window.pageYOffset + document.querySelector(arguments[0]).getBoundingClientRect().bottom > window.pageYOffset
 && 
   window.pageYOffset + document.querySelector(arguments[0]).getBoundingClientRect().top < window.pageYOffset + document.documentElement.clientHeight
 &&
   window.pageXOffset + document.querySelector(arguments[0]).getBoundingClientRect().right > window.pageXOffset
 &&
   window.pageXOffset + document.querySelector(arguments[0]).getBoundingClientRect().left < window.pageXOffset + document.documentElement.clientWidth
 )      
''', 'a.pagination-next')
```